# How to create windows on 5-minute by time interval to count repeating of words with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a CSV file which has two columns: `milliseconds` and `topics`. My CSV file looks like this:

```
 milliseconds, topics
 1.4998308E+12,today is warm
 1.4998309E+12,today is warm
 1.4998310E+12,today is warm
 1.4998314E+12,today is cold
 1.4998315E+12,today is cold
 1.4998317E+12,today is cold
 1.4998318E+12,today is cold
 1.4998320E+12,today is cold
 1.4998322E+12,today is cold
 1.4998323E+12,today is cold
 1.4998324E+12,today is cold
 1.4998326E+12,today is warm
 1.4998328E+12,today is warm
 1.4998331E+12,today is cold
 1.4998333E+12,today is warm
 1.4998336E+12,today is warm
 1.4998336E+12,today is warm
 1.4998337E+12,today is warm
 1.4998338E+12,today is snow
 1.4998339E+12,today is snow
 1.4998340E+12,today is snow
 1.4998341E+12,today is snow
 1.4998342E+12,today is warm
 1.4998343E+12,today is warm
```

How to count words in windows where each window includes 5 minutes.  The time start from 7/12/2017 6:40:00 to 7/12/2017 7:38:20.

```
 window(1) start from 6:40:00 to 6:44:00
 window(2) start from 6:45:00 to 6:49:00
 window(3) start from 6:49:00 to 6:53:00
 window(4) start from 6:54:00 to 6:58:00 
 window(5) start from 6:59:00 to 7:03:00 
 window(6) start from 7:04:00 to 7:08:00 
 etc
```

I want to count the occurence of `snow`, `warm` and `cold` on 5-minute time intervals using Python3. the result appear as:

```
 warm 3  0   0   0   0   0   2   0   1   3   0   2 total 11 
 cold 0  0   2   2   2   2   0   1   0   0   0   0 total 09
 snow 0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   1 total 4
```

where window(1)  repeating `warm` 3 times, repeating `cold` 0 times and repeating `snow` 0 times 
etc.

Comment: can you show us what you have done, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas groupby is what you need

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(<filename>)
```

first we need to format the `DataFrame` and convert from milliseconds to a `datetime`

```
topics = df['topics'].str.extract('^today is (.*)',expand=True)  # to extract the topic
topics.columns=['topic']
topics.index = pd.to_datetime(df['milliseconds'], unit='ms')
topics['count'] = 1
```

> ```
>  topics
> ```

```
milliseconds    topic   count
2017-07-12 03:40:00 warm    1
2017-07-12 03:41:40 warm    1
2017-07-12 03:43:20 warm    1
2017-07-12 03:50:00 cold    1
2017-07-12 03:51:40 cold    1
2017-07-12 03:55:00 cold    1
2017-07-12 03:56:40 cold    1
2017-07-12 04:00:00 cold    1
2017-07-12 04:03:20 cold    1
2017-07-12 04:05:00 cold    1
2017-07-12 04:06:40 cold    1
2017-07-12 04:10:00 warm    1
2017-07-12 04:13:20 warm    1
2017-07-12 04:18:20 cold    1
2017-07-12 04:21:40 warm    1
2017-07-12 04:26:40 warm    1
2017-07-12 04:26:40 warm    1
2017-07-12 04:28:20 warm    1
2017-07-12 04:30:00 snow    1
2017-07-12 04:31:40 snow    1
2017-07-12 04:33:20 snow    1
2017-07-12 04:35:00 snow    1
2017-07-12 04:36:40 warm    1
2017-07-12 04:38:20 warm    1
```

Then we group by every 5 minutes and topic

```
counts = topics.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='milliseconds', freq='5min'), 'topic']).count()

milliseconds    topic   count
2017-07-12 03:40:00 warm    3
2017-07-12 03:50:00 cold    2
2017-07-12 03:55:00 cold    2
2017-07-12 04:00:00 cold    2
2017-07-12 04:05:00 cold    2
2017-07-12 04:10:00 warm    2
2017-07-12 04:15:00 cold    1
2017-07-12 04:20:00 warm    1
2017-07-12 04:25:00 warm    3
2017-07-12 04:30:00 snow    3
2017-07-12 04:35:00 snow    1
2017-07-12 04:35:00 warm    2
```

If you want you can put the time on the columns and topics as index with `unstack`

```
results = counts.unstack('milliseconds').fillna(0).astype(int)
results.columns = range(len(results.columns))
results['total'] = results.sum(axis=1)
```

> ```
> print(results)
> ```

```
topic   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  total
cold    0   2   2   2   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   9
snow    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   1   4
warm    3   0   0   0   0   2   0   1   3   0   2   11
```

Comment: I found this error: 
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'topics'

Comment: that's because your csv has spaces in the header. either rename the columns or change the key

Comment: now I found this:
  File "C:/Users/admin/readFile/window.py", line 10, in <module>
    results = counts.unstack('milliseconds').fillna(0)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'unstack'

Comment: Thank you very much,  Maarten.